# How to know which functions available in a driver?

Tags: operating-system, driver

A device driver is a component that Windows uses to interact with a hardware device, such as a modem or network adapter. Rather than access the device directly, Windows loads device drivers and calls functions in the drivers to carry out actions on the device  but how windows know which functions are available and how to call them?

Comment: See [MSDN: DeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As far as the first part of your question, on a modern system that supports [ACPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) ([also see OSDev Wiki's page](http://wiki.osdev.org/ACPI)) Windows (or any other OS worth its salt) uses that to detect devices via the tables that are loaded by the BIOS (e.g. the [DSDT](http://wiki.osdev.org/DSDT)).